# Build a tree as a matrix in Javascript using discreet elements

Tags: javascript, tree

I want to build a matrix in JavaScript with every combination of elements in a list to a given depth.
As an example if the list contains [1,2] and my tree has a depth is 3, I would want an array of [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]].

Here's my best coding attempt so far for an options array of n elements to a depth of 3 (where n is less than 3 and options is, in this example, [1,2]):

```
for (a = 0; a < options.length; a++){
    for (b = 0; b < options.length; b++){
        for (c = 0; c < options.length; c++){
            let seq = [options[a], options[b], options[c]];
            tree.push(seq);
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like the depth to be a parameter, not hard-coded, as well as options being of variable length.

Comment: What does this have to do with vb.net? Why no javascript tag?

Comment: No reaction 14 hours later...

Comment: Vargo has recommended edits which I think address errors in my submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion, where in each level in the recursion tree you extend rows with one additional value:

```js
function createMatrix(options, depth) {
    if (depth === 0) return [[]]; // empty matrix
    let submatrix = createMatrix(options, depth - 1);
    let matrix = [];
    for (let option of options) {
        for (let row of submatrix) {
            matrix.push([option].concat(row));
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

let matrix = createMatrix([1, 2, 3], 3);
// display matrix
for (let row of matrix) console.log(...row);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, Trincot. I thought there would be a neat recursive way to crack this, but couldn't get my head around it. I've played around with your solution and it is robust. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I approached the problem by building the matrix one layer of depth at a time. With each layer, each row of the matrix is duplicated with one of the options appended.

```js
const options = [1, 2];
const depth = 3;

let matrix = []; //start matrix with 0 depth
//each iteration adds 1 more layer of depth to matrix
for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
  const newMatrix = []; //creating a new matrix where depth will be one greater than previous matrix

  //j === 0 allows first matrix layer to be added when matrix.length is 0
  //make options.length number of copies of each matrix row. Appending options[i] to each copy
  for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length || j === 0; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      //make copy of row from prev matrix and append options[i]; Adding one layer of depth
      const row = (matrix.length === 0) ? [] : matrix[j].slice();
      row.push(options[i]);
      newMatrix.push(row);
    }
  }

  matrix = newMatrix; //overwrite previous matrix
}

for (let row of matrix) console.log(...row);
```

Comment: Edit: borrowed the matrix print from @trincot

Comment: Hey, Vargo, neat piece of code. Thanks for that. I'm not a confident JavaScript programmer, so useful to have these insights. In Python it is relatively easy:

tree = [[a, b, c] for a in options for b in options for c in options]

However it does hard code the depth.